# RichFaces 4.5.2.Final Calendar page fragment breaks Arquillian Unit Test where 4.5.1 succeeded

Tags: jsf, selenium-webdriver, calendar, richfaces, jboss-arquillian

I use Arquillian Graphene to Test my Application https://github.com/phasenraum2010/javaee7-petclinic containing RichFaces Calendar:

```
<rich:calendar id="petBirthDate" locale="#{language.localeCode}"
                             value="#{ownerController.pet.birthDate}"/>
```

The Test Class uses RichFaces Page Fragments:

```
    @Test
    @InSequence(8)
    @RunAsClient
    public void testAddNewPet() {
        goTo(PetTypesPage.class);
        petTypesPage.assertPageIsLoaded();
        petTypesPage.clickAddNewPetType();
        newPetTypePage.addNewContent("cat");
        petTypesPage.clickAddNewPetType();
        newPetTypePage.addNewContent("dog");
        petTypesPage.clickAddNewPetType();
        newPetTypePage.addNewContent("mouse");
        goTo(FindOwnersPage.class);
        findOwnersPage.assertPageIsLoaded();
        findOwnersPage.clickSearch();
        ownersPage.assertPageIsLoaded();
        ownersPage.clickShowOwner();
        showOwnerPage.assertPageIsLoaded();
        showOwnerPage.clickAddNewPet();
        newPetPage.assertPageIsLoaded();
        Date birthDate1 = new Date(113, 04, 15); //15.05.2013
        Date birthDate2 = new Date(112, 07, 03); //03.08.2012
        newPetPage.setContent("Tomcat", birthDate1, "cat");
        showOwnerPage.clickAddNewPet();
        newPetPage.setContent("Bully", birthDate2, "dog");
        showOwnerPage.assertFirstPetContent("Bully", birthDate2, "dog");
        showOwnerPage.assertSecondPetContent("Tomcat", birthDate1, "cat");
    }
```

and:

```
public class NewPetPage {

    @FindBy(id="addNewPetForm")
    private WebElement addNewPetForm;

    @FindBy(id="addNewPetForm:petName")
    private WebElement petName;

    @FindBy(id="addNewPetForm:petBirthDate")
    private RichFacesCalendar petBirthDate;

    @FindBy(id="addNewPetForm:petType")
    private WebElement petType;

    @FindBy(id="addNewPetForm:add")
    private WebElement add;

    public void assertPageIsLoaded() {
        Assert.assertTrue(addNewPetForm.isDisplayed());
    }

    public void setContent(String petName, Date petBirthDate, String petType){
        this.petName.sendKeys(petName);
        DateTime dateTime = new  DateTime(petBirthDate.getTime());
        this.petBirthDate.setDate(dateTime);
        List<WebElement> options = this.petType.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
        for(WebElement option: options){
            if(option.getText().contentEquals(petType)){
                option.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        add.click();
    }
}
```

While the Test runs with success in richfaces 4.5.1 I get this with 4.5.2:

```
testAddNewPet(org.woehlke.javaee7.petclinic.web.Test04Owner)  Time elapsed: 2.774 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot open date editor. Ensure that calendar popup and header controls are displayed and some date is set.
    at org.richfaces.fragment.calendar.HeaderControls._openYearAndMonthEditor(HeaderControls.java:73)
    at org.richfaces.fragment.calendar.HeaderControls.openYearAndMonthEditor(HeaderControls.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneProxyHandler.invokeReal(GrapheneProxyHandler.java:130)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler$1.invoke(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:159)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler$2.call(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:209)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.context.BrowserActions.performAction(BrowserActions.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler.invoke(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:205)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler.intercept(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:229)
    at org.richfaces.fragment.calendar.HeaderControls$$EnhancerByGraphene$$1e72f738.openYearAndMonthEditor(<generated>)
    at org.richfaces.fragment.calendar.RichFacesAdvancedInlineCalendar.setDateTime(RichFacesAdvancedInlineCalendar.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneProxyHandler.invokeReal(GrapheneProxyHandler.java:130)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler$1.invoke(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:159)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler$2.call(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:209)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.context.BrowserActions.performAction(BrowserActions.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler.invoke(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:205)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler.intercept(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:229)
    at org.richfaces.fragment.calendar.RichFacesAdvancedInlineCalendar$$EnhancerByGraphene$$43c720e8.setDateTime(<generated>)
    at org.richfaces.fragment.calendar.RichFacesCalendar$CalendarInteractiveStrategy.setDate(RichFacesCalendar.java:90)
    at org.richfaces.fragment.calendar.RichFacesCalendar.setDate(RichFacesCalendar.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneProxyHandler.invokeReal(GrapheneProxyHandler.java:130)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler$1.invoke(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:159)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler$2.call(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:209)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.context.BrowserActions.performAction(BrowserActions.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler.invoke(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:205)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler.intercept(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:229)
    at org.richfaces.fragment.calendar.RichFacesCalendar$$EnhancerByGraphene$$cf1f649f.setDate(<generated>)
    at org.woehlke.javaee7.petclinic.web.pages.NewPetPage.setContent(NewPetPage.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneProxyHandler.invokeReal(GrapheneProxyHandler.java:130)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler$1.invoke(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:159)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler$2.call(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:209)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.context.BrowserActions.performAction(BrowserActions.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler.invoke(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:205)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.proxy.GrapheneContextualHandler.intercept(GrapheneContextualHandler.java:229)
    at org.woehlke.javaee7.petclinic.web.pages.NewPetPage$$EnhancerByGraphene$$77ffdc7c.setContent(<generated>)
    at org.woehlke.javaee7.petclinic.web.Test04Owner.testAddNewPet(Test04Owner.java:181)

testEditPet(org.woehlke.javaee7.petclinic.web.Test04Owner)  Time elapsed: 1.476 sec  <<< ERROR!
```

Question:
What am I doing wrong? or is it a Bug in RichFaces?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this. I ran all of yours tests on WildFly with both RF 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 and all of them passed.
Imho there might be a problem with unguarded HTTP/Ajax submits. Could you fix the tests to guard all the form submissions and then re-run them?

To guard requests with Graphene you can use Graphene.guard* , e.g.:

```
public void search() {
    Graphene.guardHttp(searchHTTPSubmitButton).click();
}
```

Also good practice is to wait for the element/page to load with Graphene.wait*, e.g.:

```
public void waitUntilPageIsLoaded() {
    Graphene.waitModel().until().element(someElement).is().visible();
}
```

Comment: It is a Problem of Firefox Version 35.0 and Selenium Webdriver. The Error appears also with RF 4.5.1 [https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390)